# How do I get Mail to not start up when I login to my Mac?

Tags: mac, boot, apple-mail

Whenever I login to my Mac (running OS X 10.5.8 Leopard), Mail starts up.  How do I get it to not start when I login?

It's not in my Login Items in my Accounts preferences, and Open at Login is not checked for the Mail icon on my dock.

Comment: What Login Items do you have setup? It's quite possible you have a program or an AppleScript that requires Mail to be open.

Comment: I only have iTunesHelper and QuickSilver in my Login Items, so I'm guessing neither of them are opening Mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was happening because I had an iCal alarm set up to email reminders to me.  It needed to open Mail to send the email, which happened to be almost every time I logged in to my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Check `~/Library/StartupItems` for a Mail entry. If it's in there, remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see a StartupItems directory in my Library.

Comment: thats because its a file :P